# Group_concat with complex queries or subquery output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big MySQL table `follow` that looks like the table sketched out below. It has millions of rows and thousands of `users` inside.

I'm trying to write a query with group_concat, so that for ***each*** of the users, i would pull their first/earliest 2 "following" records (based on date) and last/most recent 2 "following" (based on date) so that the results would look like the "ideal results table" below.

Any ideas? Many thanks for the help in advance.

```
follow
-------

User  |  Following  | Date
.......................................
ABCD |  1111 | 1/1/2013
ABCD |  2222 | 1/2/2013
ABCD |  3333 | 1/3/2013
ABCD | 4444  | 1/4/2013
ABCD | 5555 | 1/5/2013
ABCD | 6666 | 1/6/2013
DEFG | 1111 | 1/1/2013
DEFG | 7777 | 1/2/2013
DEFG | 3333 | 1/3/2013
DEFG | 4444 | 1/4/2013
DEFG | 5555 | 1/5/2013
HIJK | 0000 | 1/1/2013
HIJK | 2222 | 1/2/2013
HIJK | 3333 | 1/3/2013
HIJK | 4444 | 1/4/2013
HIJK | 8888 | 1/5/2013
HIJK | 9999 | 1/6/2013


Ideal result
------------

User | Following
..............................................
ABCD | 1111, 2222, 5555, 6666
DEFG | 1111, 7777, 4444, 5555
HIJK | 0000, 2222, 8888, 9999
```

Comment: I'm not going to try to write it, but here's how you go about it: Write a query that gets the first two rows of each group, union that with a query that gets the last two rows in each group, put that union in a subquery and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine them. For the first two tasks, you should be able to find SO questions that show how to do it. The last task is trivial.

Comment: @naveengoyal Why did you undo my nice formatting?

Comment: @barmar i'm confused. so what is the query i need to write? also the following table has over thousands of `user` values. so what would the query look like?

Comment: I said I'm not going to try to write it. I told you how to find out what you need to do.

Comment: @barmar problem with that approach is since i have thousands of `user` values, i would have to be writing 2 times the thousands of small, but queries (which different where clauses which i have to type in the string myself) and then try to join the individual rows/results together with union - so this approach is not really feasible. the initial ideal i had was to do `select f.user, concat(group_concat(f.following order by date asc), ', ', group_concat(f.following order by date desc)) from follow as f` but i got stuck after because i don't know how to get the limit 2 into the two group_concats

Comment: No, you don't have to write thousands of queries. You write one query that gets the first two rows in every group. You write another query that gets the last two rows in every group. You union these two queries. Then you write a parent query that uses `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the `Following` values.

Comment: Search for `[mysql] [greatest-n-per-group]` and you'll find lots of answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Barmar suggested. here's one possible version.

```
SELECT user,GROUP_CONCAT(following ORDER BY date) as following
FROM
(SELECT user,following,date FROM
 (SELECT user,following,date,
 IF (@prevUser IS NULL OR @prevUser != user,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,
 @prevUser := user
 FROM follow
 ORDER BY user,date ASC)as EarlyRecords
 WHERE row IN (1,2)
 UNION
 SELECT user,following,date FROM
 (SELECT user,following,date,
 IF (@prevUser2 IS NULL OR @prevUser2 != user,@row:=1,@row:=@row+1) as row,
 @prevUser2 := user
 FROM follow
 ORDER BY user,date DESC)as LateRecords
 WHERE row IN (1,2)
 )as AllRecords
GROUP BY user
```

The inner queries order by user,date `DESC` and `ASC` and then assign a row number so row 1 and 2 would be the lastest records or earliest records. Then they're UNION-ed together and then the outer SELECT group_concat and group by user.

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2246/22/0)

Or if you know that each one of your user will always have 4 following or more you can use this short query below

```
SELECT user,CONCAT(
                   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(following ORDER BY date asc),',',2),
                   ',',
                   SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(following ORDER BY date asc),',',-2)
                  ) as following
FROM follow
GROUP BY user
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2246/20/0)

Also your date column should be a `date` type or `datetime` type. right now it looks like `varchar` type. It works now because they all are January (1), when the year changes, or when you get Oct,Nov,Dec (10,11,12) as months your `order by date` will break if they're not the proper `date` or `datetime` type.

Comment: that big first query is probably the best answer i have so far. it works. and regarding your second point - no, some of the `user` have less than 4 following.

Comment: what happens when i need the first 5 rows and the last 5 rows for each of the user instead of the first 2 and last 2?

Comment: I just tried to change the `WHERE row IN (1,2)` clause to `where row between 1 and 5` and it appeared to fail. Any ideas as to how to fix it so that i get the first 4 rows and the last 5 rows for each user? thanks.

Comment: when I say it failed, i mean, it seems like instead of getting just a max of 4 results for each `user`, i get like the whole list despite the where `row between 1 and 5`. Any ideas?

Comment: when you don't have 10 following for each user, between 1 and 5 will just return first 5 and last 5 so for example if you have 6 following for a user, you'll just get that list of 6 following because you don't have 10 following (not enough to do first 5 and last 5) does that make sense?

Comment: what if a user have 20 following and i want to group concat only their first 5 and last 5? the `where row in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` right now gives me more than 10 following, but i really should have a max total of 10. What am i missing?

Comment: it's giving me 10 here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db1a9/2/0 I am not sure what your data looks like maybe you can sqlfiddle.com your data and I'll try to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get you answer

```
SELECT user, GROUP_CONCAT( Following ) AS following FROM `follow` GROUP BY user LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This doesn't get the first and last two values in each group.

Comment: I made a new query which matched the second query Answered by **Tin Tran** .First Query answered(the big one query) by **Tin Tran** is good . I also follow this query.

Comment: @user3116269 what happens when i need the first 5 rows and the last 5 rows for each of the user instead of just the first 2 and last 2?

Comment: when you create table then take date as a date variable e.g. **create table follow(user varchar(5),
 following varchar(5),
 date date);** and then in **WHERE row IN (1,2,3)** <-- increment with value as you want to take 4 or 5. so change it accordingly where order by clause using asc and desc. get my point?

Comment: @user3116269 so instead of writing `where row in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` i also tried writing `where row between 1 and 5`. However the group_concat results i get is weird. i still get more than 10 follow values concat-ed into 1 user. The max i should have is just 10. Any ideas?